# display a part of value in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select drop-down with country and code. In drop-down option, for user experience and understanding i am displaying name of the country along with country code. 
As a normal functionality when a user selects any value from the drop-down that value gets displayed inside the input like this

[image]

however i want that only the country code should get displayed like this

[image]

Part of my code

```
<select name="countrycode" class="form-control pf-country" id="countrycode">
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">Code</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India (+91)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option>
    <optgroup label="Other countries">
      <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
      <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

The entire code is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya001/s4ray38b/)

Can anyone please suggest how to do it.

Comment: `but i want to display only the code for that country` ==> Then only give code in option

Comment: @Anuresh I don't want to give only the numbers as everyone is not aware about which code belongs to which country. This is a feature that i want there for user, but after selecting value i want only the code to be there

Comment: did u got d and?

Comment: @Anuresh no i did not get the solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You can try this one. As this example providing exact output as you mentioned in your questions.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#selected-text

Comment: you check demo with output: https://jsfiddle.net/abbaspanjwani/dxj3eojy/14/

Comment: @user2626424 can you display the o/p inside the select tag as a selected option by user

Comment: @user2626424  Thank You

Comment: please check the demo https://jsfiddle.net/dxj3eojy/22/. In this I've displayed selected option in inside the  select tag as mentioned in your query and i've display selected value of option beside it. so you can directly use that value.

Answer (score 1):

Basically we're trying to change `innerText` of `selected-option`. It can be achieved easily by adding `onchange` event listener to the `select` tag.

But there's a little problem, on changing `innerText` we lose previous value of `innerText`, solution by @KKK solves problem but leaves this little thing.

Following code handles problem in complete ways. We're adding `data-innerText` atribute with previous value of `innerText` and also `id="previous"` to identify it. Please check this [demo](https://codepen.io/moghya/pen/eMEEoG).

```
function simpleTweak(select){  

  var previouslySelectedTag = document.getElementById('previous');
  if(previouslySelectedTag!=undefined){  
    previouslySelectedTag.innerText = previouslySelectedTag.getAttribute('data-innerText');
    previouslySelectedTag.setAttribute('id','');
  }  

  var innerText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerText;
  select.options[select.selectedIndex].setAttribute('data-innerText',innerText);
  select.options[select.selectedIndex].setAttribute('id','previous');

  var value="(+"+select.options[select.selectedIndex].value+")";
  select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerText = value;
}
```

Comment: Tried your demo, it is displaying only the code, but after selecting once, if user opens the dropdown again then the name of the country whose value was selected is disappearing

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to change the display text after selecting the option, is it? If so, you can do it like this.

You can set the selected index's text in `onchange` event. But it will reset the text in the option when you click the dropdown again. You may need to change it back if you prefer.

```js
function displayCountryCode() {
  var countrycode = document.getElementById("countrycode");
  countrycode.options[countrycode.selectedIndex].text = '+' + countrycode.value;
}
```

```html
<select name="countrycode" class="form-control pf-country" id="countrycode" onchange="displayCountryCode()">
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">Code</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India (+91)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option>
    <optgroup label="Other countries">
      <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
      <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: I thought of this solution and it works too, but it changes the display text completely, consider this

what if User wants to change the selected option? now the previously selected option does not have country name.

Comment: @moghya yes that's what I meant by "But it will reset the text in the option when you click the dropdown again". In order to overcome this issue, we need to reset this option's value if the user clicked on the dropdown again.

Comment: @KKK Tried your code, as pointed in the discussion, if user opens the dropdown again then the name of the country whose value was selected is disappearing but i do not want it to get disappeared

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript code will change the text of the selected option when you select it and change it back when you select a different one.

It does this by saving the values of the country name and country number as HTML5 data attributes (`option.dataset.countryName` & `option.dataset.countryNumber`)

Doing it this way, you don't have to change the format of the HTML from what you provided in your post.

I used vanilla JavaScript, so it'll work with or without jQuery.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let select = document.getElementsByName('countrycode')[0]
  let options = document.getElementsByTagName('option')

  for (let i = 1; i < options.length; i++) {
    let option = options[i]
    let matches =  option.innerText.match(/(.*?) (\(\+\d+\))/)
    option.dataset.countryName = matches[1]
    option.dataset.countryNumber = matches[2]

    // Set the value in the collection again now that the object has been changed
    options[i] = option
  }

  select.addEventListener('change', () => {
    for (let i = 1; i < options.length; i++) {
      let option = options[i];
      option.innerText = option.dataset.countryName + ' '
      option.innerText += option.dataset.countryNumber
    }

    let option = document.querySelector('option:checked')
    if (option !== options[0]) {
      option.innerText = option.dataset.countryNumber
    }
  })
})
```

There's also a demo [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/VAggrippino/pen/LdjjJB)